# Restricting std::async to certain CPU cores

Tags: c++

Is it possible to restrict `std::async` to use only a certain set of cpu cores? I cannot see anything in the reference for this.

I have another thread pinned to a core and I want `std::async` to avoid that core.

If this doesn't exist does anyone know whether it's planned for an upcoming version?

Comment: C++ doesn't really have the concept of a thread pool, nor cpu cores, so...

Comment: Usually, restricting access to certain cores makes apps slower. Usually the right thing to do is mess with thread priorities.

Comment: @MooingDuck Appreciate you say "usually" but this is a specific scenario. I have a critical thread which cannot be interrupted and I have N, "short" parallel tasks which cannot disturb the critical thread. It seems std::async could schedule them on the critical thread's core. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: The C++ standard does not go into cores; its libraries are at a higher level. If you want this much control you need to drop down into lower level libraries (like pthreads).

Comment: What method do you use to restrict the critical thread to that one core? Use that same method to bar the other threads from that one (restrict them to the other cores).

Comment: It depends on the OS?